# Render align environments with MathJax for 'org-html-export-to-html'

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I'm writing a document that I would like to export to LaTeX and HTML. To write my formulas I mostly use the `align` environment of TeX.

In the `.org` file I write the formulas like this:

```
#+begin_align
   a &= b + x \\
   d &= a - b \\
#+end_align
```

The export to LaTeX works as expected and I get the correct `align` environment. But for the HTML export `begin_align` and `end_align` are ignored and the ASCII text is displayed instead of a formula rendered with MathJax. The same happens if I use `\begin{align}` and `\end{align}` instead.

Standalone formulas work out of box.

How should/can I change the HTML export function to correctly display `align` environments with MathJax?

Comment: Does [this](http://orgmode.org/manual/Math-formatting-in-HTML-export.html) help?

Comment: reading the documentation it doesn't help. the align parameter in org only specifies where the functions should be placed and don't refer to the align environment.

Answer (score 2):

As the [org manual:LaTeX fragments](http://orgmode.org/manual/LaTeX-fragments.html) said, LaTeX environment should work out of box. you may mistakenly changed the default export option somewhere.

Following is a minimal example that works with `emacs -q` where the Org-mode version is `8.2.10 (release_8.2.10 @ /usr/share/emacs/25.0.50/lisp/org/)`

```
#+OPTIONS: tex:t
#+HTML_MATHJAX:  path:"http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js"
\begin{align}
   a &= b + x \\
   d &= a - b
\end{align}
```

Besides, there should no `\\` for the last equation inside LaTeX `align` environment.